# Django url not cannot find some UTF-8 usernames

Tags: django, utf-8

i am experimenting with UTF-8 for usernames in a django app.

Django is Version 3.2.11

Python used is 3.9.4

Some users might have a profile visible to others and ther username in the url:

`re_path("^u/(?P<username>\w+)/$", views.author_profile_view, name="author_profile_view"),`

Normal Example works fine:

- Browser shows -> `/u/brainyChowder3/`
- Django shows -> `GET /u/brainyChowder3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10593`

UTF-8 example 1 works also fine:

- Browser shows -> `/u/ɊȁⱲÒđΈⱦİĬd/`
- Django shows -> `GET /u/%C9%8A%C8%81%E2%B1%B2%C3%92%C4%91%CE%88%E2%B1%A6%C4%B0%C4%ACd/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12508`

But this UTF-8 does not work:

- Browser shows -> `/u/ɂáⱳ1⁄4%7Cĭğę`
- Django shows -> `"GET /u/%C9%82%C3%A1%E2%B1%B31%E2%81%844%7C%C4%AD%C4%9F%C4%99 HTTP/1.1" 404 5585`

The browser does show it strange, as he does not "translate" %7C to |, but that should be just optical?

Error shown is just

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/u/%C9%82%C3%A1%E2%B1%B31%E2%81%844%7C%C4%AD%C4%9F%C4%99
The current path, u/ɂáⱳ1⁄4|ĭğę, didn’t match any of these.
```

In Django shell I can query this user:

```
>>> User.objects.get(username='ɂáⱳ1⁄4|ĭğę')
<User: ɂáⱳ1⁄4|ĭğę>
```

The URI decoding looks ok to me.

I hope someone can explain why this is happening to one UTF-8 string, but not the other. Or maybe even knows how to fix it? :-D

I know it may not be the smartes thing to allow all UTF-8 for usernames, but this is more an experiment for me.

Thanks

Comment: Share your `urls.py`. This is because your username contains a slash.

Comment: You're missing a trailing slash in the request path?

Comment: Trailing slash makes no difference (tested). Django is configureed to add a traling slash

Comment: Relevant urlpattern is on top of the post. (re_path). And that is not slash but a E2 81 84 (FRACTION SLASH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens has nothing to do with UTF-8, but with the fact that the username contains a non-word character (a character not matched by `\w`): a character that is not allowed for the `<str:…>` path converter. You can work with a `<path:…>`:

```
path('u/<path:username>/', some_view, name='some_name')
```

Comment: unfortunately that just looks like a slash, but it is not:  Slash is 2F (SOLIDUS) but the symbol betwee 1 and 4 is  E2 81 84 (FRACTION SLASH)

Comment: @Michael: yes, but I think the solution still stands: it is due to a character that does not capture with `\w`.

Comment: Thank you, <path:..> worked! I will have a look at what path actually does. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael: it works with `.+` as regex instead of `\w+` you used.